# How to get windows newlines in ipython?

Tags: python, ipython, newline

I'm working with ipython on windows, and often I need to copy/paste some output into a text document.

Multiline output that looks fine in ipython however ends up in one line with loads of spaces, when pasted into a windows application. **How can I get ipython to behave windows like, so that the line endings work on windows?**

A minimal example would be:

```
i = 1 
while i < 5:
    print('test', i)
    i += 1
```

and results in the output (in ipython):

```
test 1
test 2 
test 3   
test 4
```

However, when I copy this from cmd window, and paste it into a texteditor (or word), it get something like this:

```
test 1                                                                                        test 2                                                                                        test 3                                                                                        test 4
```

which is quite annoying. On my linux machine, it just works as intended.

Now I suppose that has to do with the different ways that linux and windows deal with line endings/newlines, but I can't find a setting for it within ipython, which I assume is working with the linux ones, whereas windows obviously does not.

Comment: Use powershell as a terminal, cmd is crap

Comment: Gotta check out powershell, but I'd still assume that there ought to be a setting in ipython.

Comment: Powershell does not change the behavior above.

Comment: Have you tried `print('test', i, '\r\n')`?

Comment: that just adds even more spaces! Also, just specifying a matching newline in a print statement does not adress output that is not a print statement, or copying things like the loop shown above.